# Almost Surely Convergence

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I need some help with computing the lim inf and lim sup of $ \frac 1n \sum_i X_n$ where the density of variable $X_n$ is absolute continuous, say, f(x) = exp(-x). I am interested in using the Borel-Cantelli lemma, yet I am not sure how to go about it. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you describe some of the things you have considered so we can provide better guidance? Regards

Comment: The $(X_n)$ are independent, I assume?

Comment: Also, are they identically distributed? Then by the strong law of large numbers, both limits are $\mathbb{E}X_n$ I'd say.